# Technical name for this? (PIP picture in picture with transparent background via green screen, chroma key)

Tags: video-editor, editing, greenscreen

Two questions regarding this screencap:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/bS5dh.jpg

1. What's the **technical name for this**? (where you impose a PIP that contains transparency, via a green screen, so there's no rectangular border)

(reason why I want to know the technical name: so that I can search for that feature while evaluating alternative video editing programs.)

2. What FLOSS (free libre open source software) programs for Windows PC platform are out there that will let me do this? Portable programs will get first attention from me.

Comment: For #1, That's just green screening or chroma keying. There is no special name for that particular application of it.

Answer (score 2):

1. The technical name for this is a ["bug"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_on-screen_graphic). Usually the context is that it's an advertisement for another show on the same network, or it's a network logo rather than part of the content.
2. I'm not very familiar with Windows software, but [Shot Cut](https://www.shotcut.org/features/) is free and includes compositing functions.

Comment: I wouldn't call that a bug. Bug's are always branding and not part of the actual content. The usually are only generated graphics and will only incorporate short elements of actual video for promotional purposes.

Comment: That has mostly been my experience, as well. However, if you look at the software out there today, such as FCPX, you'll see that they have presets with names like "Boxes - Bug", "Bulletin Board - Bug", so I think it's relevant to list that as the name, since that's what you'll need to search for in the software if you want to make a similar effect.

Comment: Ugh, FCPX... continuing to ruin video production for everyone.